# Random Forest Model: How do I show the p-value for significantly correlated variables to target variable in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, correlation

I made a simple classification random forest model in R for my dataset of 48 variables. I'm pretty new to modeling data. I generated the Gini Impurity index and MDA metrics to determine significant variables important for the model but I couldn't find a straight-forward way to get p-values for these associations. Is there a package or code to just find variables significantly correlated with my target variable with p-values?

I came across the package randomForestExplainer which has a measure_importance function with a p-value that measures the significance of whether a variable will cause a nodal split. I think the essence of my issue is whether nodal impact in the random forest as measured by this function's metrics (MDA, Gini etc) signifies that variable is significantly correlated with the target variable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.